# VueJs search form issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/iTaurus85/pen/MqrqWj) from the book "The Majesty of Vue", it works fine. But I was trying to make the code shorter and failed.

So in the computed properies there is a function:

```
search: function(){
    var query = this.query
    return this.stories.filter(function(story){
      return story.plot.includes(query)
    });
```

I tried to remove `var query = this.query` and add directly to `return story.plot.includes(this.query)`. But this way it doesn't work. 
Why? Isn't it the same?

Comment: Duplicate TL;DR ~ `return this.stories.filter(story => story.plot.includes(this.query))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
  search () {
    return this.stories.filter((story) => {
      return story.plot.includes(this.query)
    });
  }
```